# differenciate between click X close browser and back or previous browser button in jquery/ javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, browser

I need to detect some browser events (close , previous page or right click + previous, refresh) for each event I need to show specific popup which specific buttons, I tried onbeforeunload but the problem is that works for the same way for all change events in the page, and also for the buttons in the page. 
I'm using backbone, jquery, js.

Comment: I'm sorry you can't do that.

Comment: I'm working on 2 ways : ths onbeforeunload for the closing case and history.back() for the return case but the problem is how to detect th history.back or to associate an action that can come before it

Comment: You can replace the history using pushstate and handle the back case in your router. But users will hate you for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx for your help I found the solution

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

var back = 1;
window.onload = retour;
function retour()
{
console.log("retour  "+back);
history.pushState({page: 1}, document.title, "");
back = 1-back;
}   


window.onpopstate = function(event) {
if(back)
{

alert("Return"));
history.pushState({page: 1}, document.title, "");
}
else {
history.pushState({page: 1}, document.title, "");
back = 1;
}
};



var x ;
var y ;

function checkClose(event)
{
event = event || window.event;

if(((typeof event.clientY === "undefined") && !(((x<90) && (x>60)) || (x<30))))
{
return false;
}

}
window.onbeforeunload = checkClose;

window.onmousemove = savePosition;


function savePosition(event)
{

if(event.clientX)
{
x = event.clientX;
}
if(event.clientY)
{
y = event.clientY;
}

}

</script>`enter code here`
</head>
<body>
<p>Click Back Or try to close</p>
</body>
</html>
```